# mssql isnull don't work in outer apply

Tags: sql-server, join, isnull, outer-join

```
outer apply 
( 
isnull(
    (select top 1

        sea.Daily,          
        sea.SeasonId    
    from Season as sea      
    where sea.propertyId = prop.PropertyId and FromDate < @FromDate and  ToDate > @ToDate   
    ),
    (select top 1 sea.Daily,            
        sea.SeasonId            
        from Season as sea where sea.propertyId = prop.PropertyId)
    )           
) as pri
```

Write error Incorrect syntax near ')'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing "Select"??

```
outer apply 
( 
SELECT isnull(
    (select top 1

        sea.Daily,          
        sea.SeasonId    
    from Season as sea      
    where sea.propertyId = prop.PropertyId and FromDate < @FromDate and  ToDate > @ToDate   
    ),
    (select top 1 sea.Daily,            
        sea.SeasonId            
        from Season as sea where sea.propertyId = prop.PropertyId)
    )           
) as pri
```

Raj

Comment: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @Tatti maybe you can *try* to fix the error yourself. Raj has given you the solution basically.

Comment: thanks for the tip), a lot of ideas but need a working solution

Comment: @Tatti - the error shown in your comment does not come for this code segment you have posted in your question. Post entire query

Comment: Thanks, decided to issue in a different way